# Tool chain for ARMv7l imx6 solo sd board

Tags: toolchain, yocto, linux-toolchain

I have flashed the image for a development board imx6 solo sd which is ARMv7l arch. Build by yocto project.

Now I have a application to port, for which I will be needing the tool chain, right? If yes please let me know where/how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You'll probably need a toolchain. Depending on application you want to port, you can generate a specific toolchain with yocto.

- For a Qt5 based application, the command to generate your toolchain with yocto is `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5`
- Else, if you want a toolchain based on your rootfs's image, the command to generate the toolchain will be `bitbake <image_name> -c populate_sdk`, where `<image_name>` is the name of image you builded and flashed in your board.

Comment: and what if application is based on 4.x ?

Comment: Again, depending on wich qt4 type application you want to port, you have `meta-toolchain-qt` and `meta-toolchain-qte`. I think what you'll need to use is `meta-toolchain-qte`. Follow the following link: http://developer.toradex.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux#Build_the_SDK_for_Qt_development you'll have more details.

Answer (score 0):

As John pointed out, Yocto can generate a toolchain composed of a custom GCC tolerated to your rootfs, use:

```
bitbake <image_name> -c populate_sdk
```

Alternatively, you can use the pre-built [Linaro GCC](https://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro/) and add your rootfs to the compiler command as:

```
--sysroot=/path/to/rootfs
```